# Duplicate resuts after annotation on django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I'm working with Django 1.10 with Django REST framework and need to create a filter on a relationship like this

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

class Score(models.Model):
    player = models.OneToOneField('companies.Company')

class ScorePeriod(models.Model):
    score = models.ForeignKey('Score', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    period = models.DateField()
    period_score = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

The Player filter should filter by last period_score but only if the last period is before a given year. If the year is 2015 and there are ScorePeriod for 2016 and 2015 it should filter by the 2015 period_score. In case there are 2014 and 2013 ScorePeriod and the given year is 2015 should filter by 2014.

In the views I'm using annotations so I can just filter by last_score in the filter file. This is the view.

```
queryset = super().get_queryset()
max_year = get_starting_year()

queryset = queryset.annotate(
    last_score_year_available=Max(Case(
        When(score__scoreperiod__period__year__lte=max_year,
             then=F('score__scoreperiod__period')),
        output_field=DateField()
    )),
)

queryset = queryset.annotate(
    last_score=Case(
        When(score__scoreperiod__period=F('last_score_year_available'),
             then=F('score__scoreperiod__period_score')),
        default=None,
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    ),
)

return queryset
```

This works as filter correctly but returns one duplicate for each ScorePeriod in the database. Also when getting something like "players/1" will fail because there are multiple objects in a get().